# can dynamic binding happen without using pointer and using regular object in c++

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Base{
    public:
    virtual void fun(){
        cout<<"Base"<<endl;
    }
};
class Derived:public Base{
    public:
    virtual void fun(){
        cout<<"Derived"<<endl;
    }
};
int main(){
    Derived d1;

    d1.fun(); // which binding work here? static binding or dynamic binding
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code I just want to know which binding will work in **d1.fun()** and why that binding happens ?

Comment: `d1` is  known to be of type `Derived` at compile-time, so there's nothing dynamic going on here. Can you provide some code of the sort of dynamic behaviour that you want to use without pointers? (you can use pointers, and we'll see if it's achievable without them.) Generally you'll need some run-time variable, so if it's not a pointer, it'll be something else.

Comment: Did you mean `Derived d; Base& b = d; b.fun();`? That would be dynamic binding (unless the compiler determines it can be optimized out; compiling with `-O3` in gcc will turn 
that into static binding, in this case).

Comment: As far as I know in C++ dynamic binding can only be done using a pointer or a reference (i.e. using reference semantics). It cannot be done using value semantics.

Comment: I mean that will dynamic binding possibe without pointer or reference ? does this work on regular object like d1.func() because func() is virtual function and I hear that with virtual function , compiler perform dynamic binding ? Is pointer or reference required for that?

Comment: No, it will not work without a pointer/reference.

Comment: Dynamic binding is associating a function with the dynamic type of an object, rather than with the static type of a variable. Without pointers or references, these types are the same, so dynamic binding does not do anything different from static binding.

Comment: does this mean that it will become static binding?

Comment: @LakashDangol I have explained(with examples) in which cases it will be static binding and in which it will be dynamic binding in my answer given below.

Answer (score 3):

For the call expression `d1.fun()` to work using **dynamic binding** both of the below given conditions **must be** satisfied:

1. The call should be made using a reference or a pointer to the Base class.
2. The member function `fun` should be a **virtual member function**.

If any of the above 2 conditions is not met, then we will have **static binding**.

Since in your example, `d1` is an ordinary(non-reference/ non-pointer) object, condition 1 is violated(not met), and so we have static binding.

```
int main(){
    
    Derived d1;
    Base *bPtr = &d1;
    
    bPtr->fun(); //dynamic binding 
    
    Base &bRef = d1;
    bRef.fun();  //dynamic binding 
    
    d1.fun();   //static binding
    
}
```

Comment: And note that even in the case where a pointer or reference is used if code analysis can determine the actual type of the object then the compiler is allowed to perform static binding. I.E.: void example() { derived_type d; base_type & b = d; b.func(); // static binding to derived_type::func() would be allowed } (though not mandated)

Comment: @SoronelHaetir Yes optimizations are allowed but not required.